# Cordova plugin document scanner

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-android

I need to integrate Document scanner in cordova mobile app.
I know there is a cordova-plugin-document-scanner is available. its not what i expected.

It should automatically find the document and capture it like [Scanbot Cordova Document Scanner SDK](https://scanbot.io/developer/cordova-document-scanner/) (this scanbot sdk is very expensive, so i would to get any free and open scource).  or Drop box new feature to capture document and auto sense image.

Is there any open source cordova plugin document scanner available?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to make your own version of openCV with openCV.AAR for Android to detect when a shape enters the screen then automatically take a picture then you can use that plugin.
There is no open source plugin that does what you want.

Comment: Thanks, so I need to write code in android to detect the shape and capture it. But didn't created any Cordova plugin before.